# Can I use a Chinese L Tourism Visa, then a Chinese X2 Student Visa consecutively?

Tags: visas, china

I am currently in a study abroad program for Suzhou University in China. The program begins August 20th. In anticipation, I was going to go to China two months earlier using my L Visa (which has a stay period of 60 days) to stay with friends. However, I was wondering if I just so happened to find a flight within China to go to Suzhou within my 60 day tourist day, will customs allow me to consecutively use my X2 student visa right after my L visa? And is it even possible to have both L and X2 visas at the same time?

I'm hoping to avoid having to go back to the US just for a few days, then arrive back in China with the X2 visa in effect. But if that's what I have to do, then that's that. I was just wondering if I could avoid the potential headache.

Comment: even if you do need to leave the country, going to the US is probably not necessary. A shorter, cheaper hop to a country neighbouring China that you can also get in to should to the job.

Comment: So technically I could go to Japan and then just reenter China using my X2 form?  That could possibly work. I would have to fly from Changchun to Suzhou anyways when my studies begin, so it would basically be just a layover in Japan.

Comment: You'd have to check the terms of the X2 visa, because there are occasional exceptions, but in general visas don't care with you come from, just what your citizenship is and when you enter (and when you leave). It's possible for China that even HK/Macau would work, but I don't know the details to confirm that.